# Remove directory from URL in webconfig

Tags: web-config, dotnetnuke, dnn9

I'm trying to figure out a rewrite in web.config file that removes a directory from the url.  Specifically, I'm needing to take www.domain.com/article/article-title to rewrite to www.domain.com/article-title for every url.  Can anyone help me with this please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of the IIS you may have to install the Url Rewriter module (for IIS < 10.0, that is Windows Server 1709).

A good article about how to set up rewrite rules can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)